# Distinguish between invalidated tokens and network issue with Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have a desktop app that uses Cognito to manage user authentication (through Amplify's JavaScript SDK). To support signing out a device remotely (e.g., the user wants to sign out from everywhere, or an admin wants to ban the user), I periodically call `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({ bypassCache: true })`. The problem is that when there is some network issue (server timeout/slow Internet/no Internet), this call also fails, causing my application to sign the user out. (Also with `bypassCache = false`, when the access/ID token expires, we again face the same issue).

Is there a pattern to achieve the following goals:

- If we can determine that the local tokens are invalidated, sign the user out from the local application.
- If the validity of the local tokens are indeterminable, for example due to network issues, do something else like giving the user a grace period before signing them out from the local application.